# TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, indexof

I found an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined. Am I missing something or do I need to import statements or is there an alternative? Thank you very muchenter image description here

[image]

Comment: pathname does not exist in location object. How are you passing location to Header?Can you add more code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(location)` to `({ location })`.